# NSWindow Keyword defer does not need to be escaped in argument list

Tags: swift, nswindow

Is anyone know what wrong with the following code?

```
self.m_window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(winPosX, winPosY, vWidth, modalWinHeight),
            styleMask: NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask,
            backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered, defer: false)
```

it work BUT with yellow warning message "Keyword **defer** does not need to be escaped in argument list"

Before upgrade to Xcode 7.3 with swift 2.2, the above code work fine without any warning message, the defer section look like this (Before upgrade)

```
'defer': false
```

After upgraded, I use the system recommendation auto correct, it removed the two single quote but it now show warning message? It still work, still can build and run.

Any idea what have I missed or what to do to resolve the issue?

Comment: What warning do you get after removing the single-quotes?

Comment: with the single quote, it definitely won't work, red error. Removed the single quote, it work but still showing the yellow warning message "**Keyword defer does not need to be escaped in argument list**".

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. `defer: false` compiles without any warnings. Try to clean and recompile your project.

Comment: Ok, I believed it is something to do with the Cocoapods as my project use cocoapods. The code is correct, nothing wrong but just the cocoapods didn't updated. I resolved the issue.